# Are there any common key-map for different IDEs?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellij-idea, shortcut, keymapping

I have been developing application in VSCode. My team suggested me to switch to IntelliJ. The shortcuts are new to me. Is there any universal Keymap is followed for all IDE's.

Answer (score 0):

There is a VSCode Keymap that you can install as a [VSCode Keymap](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12062-vscode-keymap) plugin and select it in [Keymap settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html).

But if you all your team use the IntelliJ IDEA and you plan to use it onwards, I would advise you to consider learning the IntelliJ IDEA's native keymap just to always be on the same pair/page with your colleagues and other IJ developers.